# Service Worker with external links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, service-worker

I´ve got a project that have external URLs and internal URLs too. It´s build with React but the Service Worker seems to cache all internal links and that is ok, but when i want to go to the external URLs it doesn´t navigate to that links, not even when it´s working online.
Is there any way to do service worker functions with external URLs?

Thank you

Edit:

I found this on github made by GoogleChromeLabs that have the answer itself... Just have to install sw tools and use the options they give https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/blob/6e8242dc328d1f1cfba624269653724b26fa94f1/README.md#toolboxroutergeturlpattern-handler-options